# Probability that a randomly chosen person watches neither basketball games nor hockey games regularly?

Tags: probability

The question is:

> Forty percent of the people in a town watch both basketball games and
> hockey games regularly. 55 percent watch basketball games and 63
> percent watch hockey games regularly. If one person is chosen
> randomly, what is the probability that this person watches neither
> basketball games nor hockey games regularly?

I've tried to construct a probability tree (which did not bear any results). I also tried to do 1 - (probability that they watch hockey, basketball, or both) however it's the final part of that equation which I seem to have trouble with. How do I calculate the probability that a randomly chosen person watches  hockey, basketball, or both?

Comment: Use the fact that $\Pr(A \cup B) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) - \Pr(A \cap B)$.

Comment: It's much easier to see what's going on if you draw a simple Venn diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If forty percent of the people watch both sports, then 15 percent watch only basketball (55-40) and 23 percent watch only hockey (63-40). Therefore we have 100-40-15-23=22 percent of people watching neither one of the sports. So if we choose a random person the probability that he/she watches neither one of the sports is 22 percent.